# Update Widget Layout on Button Click

Tags: android, kotlin

I've created a homescreen widget app and have 2 layouts with me. On Button click, the layout should be switched to layout_friday
But It's not getting updated at all :(

Given below is my Widget Code in Kotlin

```
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import com.pranav.timetableactivity.R

// Implementation of App Widget functionality.
class NewAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        appWidgetIds.forEach { appWidgetId ->
            val views: RemoteViews =
                RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.activity_friday).apply {}
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }

    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
    }

    // Enter relevant functionality for
    // when the first widget is created
    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {

    }

    // Enter relevant functionality for
    // when the last widget is disabled
    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {

    }

}
private fun pendingIntent(
    context: Context?,
    action: String

): PendingIntent {
    val intent= Intent(context,NewAppWidget::class.java)
    intent.action=action

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )

}
    internal fun updateAppWidget(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetId: Int
    ) {
        val widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text)
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.activity_friday).apply {}
        //views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText)

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        updateAppWidget(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetId)
    }
```

I tried to update the view by calling AppWidgetManager but still it's not working and I'm a newbie to Kotlin Development